# SQLite and joins

Tags: sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sqlite replace values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43813/sqlite-replace-values)

I have one table in sqlite called images and it contains a column named "index" and i have created another column which is empty and is named tilename. the first column index has values like 2530CA_16 and 2832AB_13 and would like the same values to be inserted into the new column called tilename but without the _ for example i want  it to be like
 old column "index" value 2530CA_16 should be newcolumn tilename value 2530CA16

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is really a good fit for GIS.SE, but perhaps you can make the data available and show the code you've currently tried? Clearly the answer is going to involve some kind of
`UPDATE images SET tilename = substr(index,1,6) + substr(index,7,8)`
but I'd like to make sure the solution fits with your needs.

Comment: the solution does not completely work as it just shows the first four digits only whilst it is supposed to show all the values except the _ only. for instance 2530CA_16 should become 2530CA16. i do not have a clue because i thought the update would do it as well but specifically i do not know

Comment: Does "first four digits" mean "2530" in this case? Can I again ask that you make available the data and the code that you have - its hard to understand the issue from your description.

Comment: thanks for the help i solved it, i had a table with a column "index" which had values 2530CA_16 and it was supposed to be transfered to the other column so that it became 2530CA16. so i did the following

Comment: update table set tilename=index and then update images set tilename =   replace (tilename,'_', '')