# sqlite replace values

Tags: sqlite

i have a table with two columns: one named `index` and the other is called `tilenumber` and the `tilenumber` is populated from the `index` column except that there is `_` which needs to be removed from the column.

The index table has values like **2726BA_11** and the tilenumber should result in 2726BA11 but i seem not to know the way forward, to remove the space i have done the following:

```
select distinct replace (tilenumber,'_', '') from aug2012
```

and it shows that the result has been achieved but how do i incorporate the select distinct replace in the update statement which is

```
update set tilenumber="index"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is really the place for basic SQL, but I guess it is loosely related to GIS....

This is pretty basic stuff, you really need to read about SQL if you're trying to do anything in GIS with it:

```
update yourtable set tilenumber = replace(index,'_','')
```

I would start with the basics of SQL itself (e.g http://sqlzoo.net/ and then move onto the sqlite3 documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) as that's a bit more esoteric.